# How to merge list of dataframes with external dataframe into a new single dataframe?

Tags: r

I Have a list of 51 dataframes that look like this:

```
GENOME_1 <- data.frame(COG = c("a","b","c"), GEN_1 = c("names","morenames","diferent_genenames"))

GENOME_2 <- data.frame(COG = c("a","b","c","d"), GEN_2 = c("names","names", "differen_genenames","somemorenames"))

GENOME_3 <- data.frame(COG = c("a","c"), GEN_3 = c("names","different_genenames"))
```

I have my dataframes organized in a list

I have a dataframe which is not part of this list which looks like this

reference <-data.frame(COG = c("a","b","c","d","e"), Names = c("names","morenames","diferent_genenames","somemorenames","namesonlyfoundhere"))

This dataframe has many more rows than the rest around 800 rows.

I would like to merge each of the individual dataframes with the  external dataframe creating a single new dataframe that could look like this

```
Dataframe_final <-data.frame(COG = c("a","b","c","d","e"), Names = c("names","morenames","diferent_genenames","somemorenames","namesonlyfoundhere"), GEN_1 = c("names","morenames","diferent_genenames", "NA", "NA"),GEN_2 = c("names","morenames", "differen_genenames","somemorenames", "NA"), GEN_3 = c("names","different_genenames", "NA","NA","NA"))
```

I tried using the following loop

```
for (i in seq_along(list_ofdataframes)) {newtable <- merge(reference, list_ofdataframes[[i]], by = "COG", all = T)}
```

And I get something similar to the result I want , but not quite

It creates a new table where the values are merged as I would want but only for one of the values the last one apparently it looks like this:

```
Dataframe_final <-data.frame(COG = c("a","b","c","d","e"), Names = c("names","morenames","diferent_genenames","somemorenames","namesonlyfoundhere"),GEN_3 = c("names","different_genenames", "NA","NA","NA"))
```

EDIT: I found it to work using the following command : finaldd<- Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "COG", all = TRUE),list(GENOME_1,GENOME_2,GENOME_3,reference))

> View(finaldd)
> but

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example with data (use dput()) so the question could be answered. Not full data needed, only an example that can represent your problem entirely.

Comment: Hellow thanks for your feedback im quite new at the website I edited my answer and added reproducible examples as you suggested, thanks beforehand.